# How to make custom dashboard widget to display alert in front-end?

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I need to make a widget to display any alert in front end

The widget is in dashboard section on backend and any user can use yet.

The content of the widget in dashboard is:

- Welcome message
- On/off (with checkbox or select option) to display alert section in the front end
- Green/red selector in backend to display in the front-end with any
  message, for example: If red color "Stop!" else green color "Go!"
- Textarea for any message to display under the red/green area in the
  front end
- Finally submit button.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) to learn about [Adding A Dashboard Widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) at which point in the dashboard widget callback you can add your form or whatever you need.

Toward the top of your callback function you could add a test to check if a form posted

`if(isset($_POST))`

Then you can save your values, maybe using [`update_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) which will save your information to your database. If the `$_POST`ed value doens't exist or is empty, you can then use [`delete_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_option) to remove it from your database.

Finally to get it on the front end you can use [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) which will return your saved value or `FALSE` if the option does not exists.

That's just one idea though off the top of my head. There may be better or faster ways to go about it but that's how I would do it. Good Luck!